# For existing entity on Google Cloud Datastore I would like to add a new property as a Blob?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud, datastore

For existing entity on Google Cloud Datastore I would like to add a new property "s11_data" for all of the keys within that entity. I click on a key and click on New Property and name it appropriately, save, and voila. It is now a property column [set to null] for all of the keys. But I want this property to be a Blob (like some of the existing entries are already). If I click one of the existing entries, then "Blob" is an option in the drop-down menu of the property pane.

But it is not an option for the new property. I *thought* the resolution was to be sure to turn off indexing. But nope, even with Index unchecked the Blob option does not appear.

I'm happy to set it via Python is that is best way forward, but I can't work that out either (I can `client.put()` a property value but cannot find how to assign a property type.

Suggestions appreciated. Thanks,

Edit: here is the drop-down menu showing "Blob"[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to do it in code via Python, then I don't believe `blob` is a property if you're using the `datastore library` (see [types](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/2.6.1/entities.html)). But you can get it as a property if you're using the `ndb library`

1. If you're using the `bundled ndb library`, then you can set the property type in your model definition (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#properties_and_value_types) for property types) e.g.

```
    s11_data = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

2. If you're using `cloud ndb library`, you also define it in model definition (see [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/model.html)) e.g.

```
    class YourModel(Model):
        s11_data = BlobProperty()
```

3. It looks like you can also specify a blob if you're directly making REST API calls. Refer to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) (see blobValue field)

Comment: I think NDB is deprecated isnt it? I am using Cloud Datastore... I've uploaded a picture showing "Blob" as a drop-down option. But you make an interesting point. This database was migrated from NDB.... Maybe in the old days you could define property as a Blob, and maybe when "old" properties are read by Datastore then it is perfectly happy to discover a Blob. But it wont let me create a new property with that type...

Comment: No, NDB isn't deprecated (I provided links to the documentation in my answer). The bundled NDB API (```from google.appengine.ext import ndb```) was initially not available for Python 3 but this changed sometime last year. The Cloud version of NDB is available (see link in my answer). The limitation with Blob is one of the advantages of using the NDB library over the Datastore library

Answer (score 0):

Actually easier than I thought. Just write a bytes class and Google automatically sets it as a Blob

```
json_data = {}
json_data["V"] = 0.123
json_data["Q"] = 4. 
a = codecs.encode(json.dumps(json_data).encode('utf-8'), encoding='zlib_codec')

with client.transaction():    
   task = client.get(key)    
   task["s11_data"] = a
   client.put(task)
```

[image: google snapshot]